# Scrabble cs50 computescore

Tags: c, cs50, scrabble

Some of the preset responses are not being checked correctly.

Please don't give the answer, just hoping to get some guidance on how to improve.

preset responses: "hai!" should win over "Oh," , "COMPUTER" should win over "science" .

Below is my code for the computescore function;

```
int compute_score(string word)
{
    int j = strlen(word);
    int total = 0;
    int index;
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        char c = word[i];
        if (isupper(c))
        {
            c = c - 65;
            index = c;
            total = POINTS[index];
        }
    
        if (islower(c))
        {
            c = c - 97;
            index = c;
            total = POINTS[index];
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you are trying to make a summation of the character score values.

This line reassigns the `total` variable to the latest singular point value every iteration:

```
total = POINTS[index];
```

If you had a look at the value of `total` after the `for` loop, you'd find it to be the value of the last valid character in the string.

Instead, use the [plus-equals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment) operator to add on as you go:

```
total += POINTS[index];
```

And don't forget to return something from that function.

Comment: Just a reminder: `total += x;` is shorthand for `total = total + x;`